# Concurrent modification during iteration: _LinkedHashSet

Tags: flutter, flame

I am following [this game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qk_jJIjg5s&t=503s) but with a new version of Flame. So the game code is not exactly the same. The difference here in this class is that the method `addChild` used in tutorial doesn't exist anymore, it seems.

I have this code inside my EnemyManager`

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/sprite.dart';
import 'package:game_template/src/game_internals/game/enemy.dart';
import 'package:game_template/src/game_internals/game/game.dart';

class EnemyManager extends Component with HasGameRef<Space>{
  late Timer timer;
  final Random random = Random();
  final SpriteSheet spriteSheet;
  EnemyManager({
    required this.spriteSheet
}) {
    timer = Timer(1, onTick:  _spawnEnemy, repeat: true );
  }
  void _spawnEnemy() {
    final initialSize = Vector2(64, 64);
    final position = Vector2(random.nextDouble() * gameRef.size.x, 0);
    position.clamp(Vector2.zero() + initialSize/2, gameRef.size - initialSize/2);
    gameRef.add(Enemy(sprite: spriteSheet.getSpriteById(6), size: initialSize, position: position));
  }

  @override
  void onMount() {
    super.onMount();
    timer.start();
  }

  @override
  void onRemove() {
    super.onRemove();
    timer.stop();
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    super.update(dt);
    timer.update(dt);
  }
}
```

The problem is after running for a few seconds, I am getting this exception:

```
======== Exception caught by scheduler library =====================================================
The following ConcurrentModificationError was thrown during a scheduler callback:

> Concurrent modification during iteration: _LinkedHashSet len:5.
> 
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
> #0      _CompactIterator.moveNext (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:705:7)
> #1      ExpandIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:475:32)
> #2      IterableMixin.forEach (dart:collection/iterable.dart:45:23)
> #3      FlameGame.updateTree (package:flame/src/game/flame_game.dart:80:14)
> #4      FlameGame.update (package:flame/src/game/flame_game.dart:69:7)
> #5      GameRenderBox.gameLoopCallback (package:flame/src/game/game_render_box.dart:55:10)
> #6      GameLoop._tick (package:flame/src/game/game_loop.dart:46:13)
> #7      Ticker._tick (package:flutter/src/scheduler/ticker.dart:238:12)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Flame, but it seems unlikely to me that the code you've shown causes the error.  The stack trace also does not seem to refer to this code.  The error indicates that a `Set`/`LinkedHashSet` is being modified while it's being iterated over.

Comment: Yes, the code's add call clashes with the framework. Not sure what is the best place to call add here.

Comment: How did you determine that the `add` call is the problem?  The documentation for [`FlameGame.add`](https://pub.dev/documentation/flame/latest/components/Component/add.html) says that it "**Schedules** `component` to be added..." (emphasis mine), which means that isn't done immediately.  Additionally, it explicitly states: "This method is robust towards being called from any place in the user code: you can call it while iterating over the component tree...".

Comment: Based on the answer blow. Beside, this is the only thing in the code that changes that list of components.

Comment: As you noted, that answer is wrong, so the premise that `add` is responsible seems incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

So to confirm and clarify. The posted code works as expected. The bug was somewhere else, and by some unfortunate coincidence, it happened after I wrote this code.
`add` method is safe, and we don't need to do anything to accommodate game loop.

Answer (score 0):

It is the timer that is causing this exception, since it can modify the child set while the game is going through it.
You can add it to a list instead of to the `gameRef` in `_spawnEnemy` and then you add that list in `update`.

Something like this:

```dart
  final enemies = [];

  void _spawnEnemy() {
    final initialSize = Vector2(64, 64);
    final position = Vector2(random.nextDouble() * gameRef.size.x, 0);
    position.clamp(Vector2.zero() + initialSize/2, gameRef.size - initialSize/2);
    enemies.add(Enemy(sprite: spriteSheet.getSpriteById(6), size: initialSize, position: position));
  }


  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    super.update(dt);
    timer.update(dt);
    if(enemies.isNotEmpty) {
      gameRef.addAll(enemies);
      enemies.clear();
    }
  }
```

(`addChild` is just called `add` now)

Comment: That didn't help. I still get the same exception.

Comment: [The documentation to `FlameGame.add`](https://pub.dev/documentation/flame/latest/components/Component/add.html) states: "This method is robust towards being called from any place in the user code: you can call it while iterating over the component tree...", so I doubt that it is the problem.

Comment: That's true, are you sure that you are running the latest version of Flame @Arash?